# Weighted Standard Deviation in PHP code

Tags: php, statistics, usage-statistics

```
a1 = [14, 12, 11, 9, 9, 8, 8]
a2 = [12, 13, 14, 9, 9, 8]
...
...

std_dev_a1 = 2.267786838
std_dev_a2 = 2.483277404
...
...
```

a3 is composed of a1 and a2,

```
a3 = [14, 12, 11, 9, 9, 8, 8, 12, 13, 14, 9, 9, 8]
std_dev_a3 = 2.295480509
```

of course I cannot do that by 
std_dev_a3 != (std_dev_a1 * 7 + std_dev_a2 * 6) / 13

My question is:
can I get **std_dev_a3** only by **std_dev_a1 and std_dev_a2**?

The problem arises when I code in PHP to calculate an array's stddev.
Because the array keeps growing, it will run out of memory finally. 
Thus, I unset() array in each iteration, then the problems comes out.
The things I saved from last iteration are average of array, stddev, length of array,
so is it possible to calculate std_dev of a new array which is based on old array plus new array?

Answer (score 1):

You can't calculate it exactly because the standard deviation formula computes the difference between each element against the average.

But you can get a good approximation by the following formula:

```
std_dev_a3 = (n1 - 1)*pow(std_dev_a1, 2) + (n2 - 1)*pow(std_dev_a2, 2)
std_dev_a3 = sqrt(std_dev_a3 / (n1 + n2 - 2))
```

You mentioned that you use this approach because you have memory leak.

You can avoid a memory leak storing your data into a frequency table:

```
{[8] => 3, [9] => 4, ..., [14] => 2}
```

With this data structure, you can calculate the standard deviation:

```
// This should be provide by your data
$freq = array(8 => 3, 9 => 4, 11 => 1, 12 => 2, 13 => 1, 14 => 2);

// Calculate mean
$mean = 0;
$n = 0;

foreach ($freq as $value => $count) {
  $mean += $value * $count;
  $n += $count;
}

$mean = $mean / $n;

// Calculate std dev
$std_dev = 0;

foreach ($freq as $value => $count) {
  $std_dev += ($count * pow($value - $mean, 2));
}

$std_dev = sqrt($std_dev/($n - 1));
```

Comment: This formula is used by t-tests, etc. I updated the post with another approach.